Help Identifying IC with Marking "P2055 TI318 A3C2"
I have an IC that I am trying to identify. It is marked with the following:
P2055
TI318
A3C2
I've done some preliminary research, however, I haven't been able to find a definitive datasheet or more information about this part.
Here is an image of the IC for reference:

Does anyone recognize this IC or have suggestions on where I could find its datasheet? Any help in identifying the function or manufacturer of this IC would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Can't seem to find the exact IC but seeing "TI" and that font is ubiquitous to Texas Instruments .

It's definitely a Texas Instruments part, but it doesn't show up in their own part lookup. This means that it's likely a customer specific part with no public information available. Your best bet is probably asking TI directly.

Thank you for your input! I've already reached out to Texas Instruments for further clarification. In addition, I used the Part Marking Lookup tool to search for "2055," and the TPS922055 came up as a potential match. This IC seems to have the same pin count and aligns closely with the functionality I was expecting, particularly in terms of power control.
